# Sum of first n-Numbers in string in R separated by Underline Bar

Tags: r, regex, split

I'm currently dealing with data from a travel survey. Tour information is given in an odd string format:

```
tours <- c("Home_work_service_leisure_business_leisure_Home", "Home_service_work_Home", "Home_leisure_shopping_leisure_education_Home")
distance <-  c("0_1.7_0.5_2.4_0.8_1.8_0", "0_5.2_7_0", "0_2.8_3_0.2_1.9_0")
primary_act <-  c(1, 2, 4)
# "home" is not considered an activity and thus it is activity zero. 

Travel_survey <- data.frame(tours, distance , primary_act)
```

From this data I want to extract the total distance to the primary activity. This means I want to sum up the trip distance until work or education.
So in our example the result should be:

```
Travel_survey$distance_primact <- c(0.17, 12.2, 7.9)
```

What I managed to do is to split the distance string and to sum the values. However, I want to tell the function to sum only the first n-values, whereas n is equal to primary_act.

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(Travel_survey$distance), "_"),
       function(x) sum(as.numeric(x), na.rm=TRUE))
```

Is there anyone who has an idea how to do this? I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Not clear how you are getting `distance_primact`. Can you show with an example? How it is "0.17" for first row?

Comment: The first one should be 0 + 1.7 = 1.7 ... right?

Comment: this is correct the first one is 0+1.7

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
library(magrittr)
touri<-Travel_survey$tours %>% as.character %>% strsplit(.,"_")
disti<-Travel_survey$distance %>% as.character %>% strsplit(.,"_") %>% lapply(.,as.numeric)

touri<-lapply(touri,function(x) { 1:grep(pattern="(?i)work|education",x) })

mapply(function(d,nums){sum(d[nums],na.rm=F)},d=disti,nums=touri)
#[1]  1.7 12.2  7.9
```

please note:

You can of course subtract the `primary_act` from these raw data. This step remains unclear in your question.

```
Travel_survey$distance_primact <- mapply(function(d,nums){sum(d[nums],na.rm=F)},d=disti,nums=touri) - primary_act
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. However I cannot identify `touri` with grep as there are tours like this: `"Home_work_service_leisure_education_leisure_Home"`  it is then up to some person specification if work or education is the primary activity.  This is why the identification of the primary activity has to be done somehow via `primary_act`

Comment: "of course subtract the `primary_act` from these raw data". How?

Comment: by using the `-` operator.